# taking values from user through signup page using ModelForm in django

Tags: django, modelform

I am making a signup page using django ModelForm.
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

country_choices=(
    ('india','INDIA'),
    ('egypt','EGYPT'),
    ('germany','GERMANY'),
    ('afghanistan','AFGHANISTAN'),
    ('switzerland','SWITZERLAND'),
    ('usa','USA'),
    ('mexico','MEXICO'),
    )


class user(models.Model):
    uid=models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=0)
    uname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phoneno=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    addr1=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    addr2=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=country_choices)
    pincode=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    securityq=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    securitya=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.uid,self.uname

    class Meta:
        db_table="user"

class userForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= user
        fields= ['uid','uname','email','password','phoneno','addr1','addr2','city','state','country','pincode','securityq','securitya']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import userForm

def homepage(request):
    return render(request,'student/homepage.html',)

def signuppage(request):
    return render(request,'student/signuppage.html',)

def get_userdetails(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=userForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form=form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('student/signuppage.html')
        else:
            form=userForm()
        return render(request,'student/homepage.html',{'form':form})
```

signuppage.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'student/signupcss.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <section id="content">

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <h1>Create an Account</h1>
            {{form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

    </section>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But it displays a blank form with only "Create my account" and a "Submit" button when i access /student/signuppage.html  ...there are no textboxes or dropdowns...aren't they supposed to be generated automatically?

Do i need to make forms.py with Modelforms also?...if yes then what would i put inside that?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you make a `GET` request to your view, but look closely how it is structured:

```
def get_userdetails(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
        if form.is_valid():
            # ...
        else:
            # ...

        return render(request, 'student/homepage.html', {'form':form})
```

You can clearly see that there is no handling of what happens when `request.method` is different from `POST`.

Actually, there is, you have written it, but you need to move the `else` statement to be for the **outer** `if` (`if request.method == 'POST'`). [In the Django docs there is the same example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view).

So you need to make your view like:

```
def get_userdetails(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('student/signuppage.html')
    else:                                                           # <<<
        form = userForm()                                           # <<<
                                                                    # <<<
    return render(request, 'student/homepage.html', {'form':form})  # <<<
```

Comment: did that...still nothing.